# Render something in React only if a condition is met?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an App displaying data from an API a page at a time. 
I want to only display the back button only when the value of pageNumber is > 1. Struggling to understand why it won't allow me to write a simple if statement.

Here is the code:

```
const TopRatedPage = () => {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
  const { results = [] } = apiData;

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetchTopRatedMovies(pageNumber).then((data) => setApiData(data));
    setLoading(false);
  }, [pageNumber]);

  return (
    <div className='top-rated-page-wrapper'>
      <h1>TopRatedPage</h1>
      {isLoading ? <h1>Loading...</h1> : <MovieList results={results} />}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setPageNumber(pageNumber + 1);
        }}>
        MORE
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setPageNumber(pageNumber - 1);
        }}>
        BACK
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

My aim is to make the BACK button invisible is the pageNumber unless the value is > 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to condition its display off the `pageNumber`:

```
{pageNumber > 1 && <button
  onClick={() => {
    setPageNumber(pageNumber - 1);
  }}>
    BACK
</button>}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return (
        <div className='top-rated-page-wrapper'>
            <h1>TopRatedPage</h1>
            {isLoading ? <h1>Loading...</h1> : <MovieList results={results} />}
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                setPageNumber(pageNumber + 1);
                }}>
                    MORE
                </button>
            {pageNumber > 1 && (
                <button
                    onClick={() => {
                    setPageNumber(pageNumber - 1);
                }}>
                    BACK
                </button>
            )}
        </div>
    );
```